# Lies of the Desert Fathers

Tags: morality, good-and-evil, ethics, deception, lying

Reading *The Sayings of the Desert Fathers*, I came across at least two accounts of the Fathers lying to or deceiving people

> 10 . Once a provincial judge heard of Abba Moses and went  to Scete to see
>   him. They told the old man that he was on his  way, and he rose up to
>   flee into a marsh. The judge and his  train met him, and asked: "Tell
>   me, old man, where is the cell  of Abba Moses?" And the old man said:
>   "Why do you want to  see him? He is a fool and a heretic."
>   The judge came to the church, and said to the clergy: "I  heard of
>   Abba Moses and came to see him- But an old man on  his way to Egypt
>   met me, and I asked him where was the cell  of Abba Moses. And he
>   said: 'Why are you looking for him? He  is a fool and a heretic.* "
>   And the clergy were distressed and  said: "What sort of person was
>   your old man who told you this  about the holy man?" And they said:
>   "He was an old man, tall  and dark, wearing the oldest possible
>   clothes.'* And the clergy  said: "That was Abba Moses. And he told you
>   this about him-  self because he did not want you to see him." And the
>   judge  went away much edified.
>
> 17 . A magistrate came to see Abba Simon one day. When he heard  of it, he
>   put on his apron and went out to attend to a palm-tree.  When the
>   visitors arrived they called out to him, 'Old man, where  is the
>   anchorite?' He replied, 'There is no anchorite here.' Hearing  these
>   words, they went away again.

<sup>Source: *THE SAYINGS OF THE FATHERS, PART VIII in "The Library Of Christian Classics Volume XII. Western Asceticism" by Owen Chadwick, 1958*</sup>

Having read many other anecdotes about the Desert Fathers and knowing how much they valued eremitic lifestyle and detachment from the world I take the behavior of these two abbas as an attempt to avoid being bothered by unexpected and random visitors lest they disturb their seclusion and peace of mind.

Abba Moses (the protagonist of the first anecdote above) is recorded as saying

> 10 . "A man who avoids men is like a ripe grape. A man who companies with men is like a sour grape"

<sup>Source: *ibid, Part II*</sup>

Various sources, for example [gotquestions.org](https://www.gotquestions.org/Bible-lying-sin.html), assert that lying is regarded as a sinful act.

So I would guess that by being deliberately untruthful these Fathers not only acted presumably unethically and sinfully, they also acted against the ethos of Jesus's teachings expressed in such saying as

> If anyone forces you to go one mile, go with them two miles. Give to
>   the one who asks you, and do not turn away from the one who wants to
>   borrow from you.

Mt 5:41-42

In the quoted stories the visitors were going to ask for advice and borrow some wisdom, which they were denied under false pretenses, `although in the first case the visitor is said to have still derived benefit from witnessing the abba's humbleness, which nevertheless could have been a byproduct and not the original intent`.

**My question thus is whether and how these Fathers' deceptive behavior could be justified from the Christian doctrine point of view, either Catholic or Greek Orthodox denomination?**

- Obviously the purpose of these anecdotes was and is to serve as
  examples of good Christian ascetic conduct and so recording these two
  particular ones their authors must've not viewed the conduct of the
  abbas as either deceitful or as a morally reproachable deceit (if
  deceit can be morally neutral or even positive) possibly knowing a good excuse for it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these stories, but reading the first one, it doesn't necessarily sound deceitful. Abba Moses may have actually had a guilty conscience and was telling the truth.

Comment: Luke's first meeting with Yoda?

Comment: @4castle yes, indeed it's a possibility, i've made  allowance for that, but it remains a conjecture

Comment: I have edited out your appeal to the mods.  If you want to discuss why the question is or isn't on hold, please make a post in [meta](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/).   I slightly edited your bottom line question to tighten the scop to only catholic and greek orthodox.  As  you had it asked, it was far too broad in scope.  HOpefully, it will get a few reopen votes.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast i appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Truth is in the 'eye of the beholder'.

What the other people thought about Abba Moses may not necessarily have portrayed him correctly. An alternative explanation is that Abba Moses had low thoughts about himself, according to the old saying:

> Mat 23:12 (NIV) "For those who exalt themselves will be humbled, and those who humble themselves will be exalted".

The judge seems to have been taking it that way, anyway, which is reflected in the words of the storyteller: "the judge went away much edified".

Comment: Abba Moses must have wanted to know, like the Lord Himself had done, what the people thought of him. The attributes he used for himself, could be seen as projection of his sense of humor.  On the other hand, the judge was not 2.0 earnest in the pursuit of the saintly man in that he was easily turned away by the saying of `an old man' !

Comment: The anecdote "truth is in the eye of the beholder" is about as anti-Christian a statement as you can get, except for a few modern & post-modern movements that have embraced relativism. Historically almost all branches of Christianity have revolved around affirmations of absolute truth.

Comment: Hmm, the last time I checked, an anti magic ray is what's in the [eye of the Beholder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beholder_%28Dungeons_%26_Dragons%29). :)  As Caleb noted, your first sentence could be deleted and not only not harm your answer, but actually improve it. :)

Comment: "Truth is in the eye of the beholder", means that people see other people differently. Humans judge often according to appearances, but appearances can be deceptive (John 7:24). So, the saying: "Truth is in the eye of the beholder" is accurately portraying the common, but not perfect, norm. The judge in the story, was edified, but another person in the same situation could have read the encounter with Abba Moses differently.

Comment: Thus, there is a clear difference between 'truth about life', which Jesus claims himself to be (John 14:6), and 'truth about people', who we are encouraged by Jesus to judge lightly, if at all (Mat 7:1)